# Assign linux command output to variable in python 2.6.6

Tags: linux, shell, python

I am trying to port a shell script to python. Used various methods from google search, but none of them seems to work.

This is the shell command.

```
version=`awk '{print $5}' file_name | tr -d ")" `
```

These are the methods tried.

```
version = subprocess.call(['awk','{print $5}','file_name','|','tr','-d'], shell=True)
version = os.system("`awk '{print $5}' file_name | tr -d ")" `", shell=True)
version = commands.getstatusoutput(" awk '{print $5}' file_name | tr -d ")"  ")
```

Neither of the above commands worked. Could someone please help me with it.

Comment: If your idea of "porting" a shell script to Python is to wrap the shell calls up with `os.system()` then there's pretty much no point in the exercise whatsoever.

Comment: I agree with you. But, initially I wanted to make the script run as a python script and later port each possible function to use python library. It does look like a double work, I'll now try directly to use python instead of shell calls(I am new to using python, but that's no excuse I guess).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your examples have various quoting errors.

The most straightforward solution would be:

```
subprocess.call('awk \'{print $5}\' file_name | tr -d ")"', shell=True)
```

but that's not recommended, because file_name can contain spaces (you can get around by shell=False and proper use of list of arguments, but it's getting unreadable).

I'd suggest `str.replace(')', '')` insted of `tr -d`, and  something like`x.split()[4] for x in open('file_name')` instead of `awk`, to get a pure python version.